# How to avoid Qt Test from timing out after 600s

Tags: qt, testing, qttest

Is it possible to ignore the MAX_VALUE of 600 sec at Qt-testing?
I try:

```
qputenv("QTEST_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT", "1000000"); // 1'000 sec
```

but the result is:

```
System.Exception: Process timed out: 600s
```

So it is possible to increase the timeout from 300s to 600s.
The problem is, I need in one case 800 sec, how can I realize that?

[Setting timeout to Qt Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655932/setting-timeout-to-qt-test)

Comment: You must call `qputenv` before `QTest::qExec` for this to work.

Comment: @RA. I tried your solution, but I still have the same effect - Why is there a limit of 600s? :(

Comment: I won't be able to help you further unless you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The output you've provided (`System.Exception: Process timed out: 600s`) does not appear to be generated by the Qt unit testing framework.  Qt simply prints `Test function timed out` when the time out has been reached.

Comment: @RA. `QTest::qExec()` executed in `QTEST_MAIN()` macro so seems need to set env var in the test constructor.